# how to get securityContext property in ADF using Groovy Expression

Tags: java, oracle, groovy, expression, oracle-adf

I am currently working on an ADF Application & I just get a securityContext property by using this groovy expression "adf.context.securityContext.get('dCode')" and it will gives me this below error.

error:
Exception in expression "dCode" bound parameter value expression : oracle.jbo.script.ExprSecurityException Accessing the sessionScope property on class oracle.adf.share.http.ServletADFContext is not permitted.
at "dCode" BoundParameter line 1

I tried my best to solve this error but I can't. Please help me to resolve this error.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the groovy expression, through source mode, please ensure that , `trustMode='trusted'`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell us your exact JDev version, Please?

Have you set the expression to 'trusted'?

See https://andrejusb.blogspot.com/2017/04/adf-bc-groovy-expression-security.html for the full description.